# How to obtain a list of the differences between the (nth +1) element of another list with the nth element of the same list?

Tags: list-manipulation

Let's say I have this list: `mylist = {a, b, c, d, e, f}`.
My goal is to obtain this list: `goal = {(b-a), (c-b), (d-c), (e-d), (f-e)}`  so that the first element of `goal` is the second element of `mylist` minus the first element of `mylist`, and so on. I am new to mathematica and I have no idea how to create such a list...

Comment: Look up `Differences[]`.

Comment: Look at what `Rest[mylist]` gives you and what `Most[mylist]` gives you and then what `Rest[mylist]-Most[mylist]` gives you. Look up both those functions in the help system and study them until you understand what they do. then think about this until you understand how it is working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mylist = {a, b, c, d, e, f}
goal=mylist // #[[2 ;;]] - #[[1 ;; -2]] &
```